# Can "recollect" be followed by an infinitive?

Tags: verbs

**I recollected to write her every day.**

Is the sentence correct? I think it's wrong. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

It certainly sounds odd and unnatural. But the problem is that we don't usually use "recollect" in that way. The sentence

> I remembered to write her every day.

has the same grammatical structure, but sounds quite natural. The word
"recollected" is normally followed by a description or specification of a past event, or some other thing that is being recalled to mind, not a task.

The [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionar) is:

> transitive verb
> 1 : to bring back to the level of conscious awareness : remember
> *trying to recollect the name*
> 2 : to remind (oneself) of something temporarily forgotten
>
> intransitive verb
> : to call something to mind

The [Collins definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/recollect) is similar:

> transitive verb
> If you recollect something, you remember it.
> *Ramona spoke with warmth when she recollected the doctor who used to be at the community hospital.*
> Synonyms: remember, mind [dialect], recall, reminisce

The [Cambridge def](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/recollect) is:

> To remember something:
>
> - Can you recollect his name?
> - As far as I can recollect, his name is Edward.
> - [ + (that) ] She suddenly recollected (that) she had left her jacket in the restaurant.
> - [ + question word ] Do you recollect where she went?
> - [ + -ing verb ] He does not recollect seeing her at the party.
>
> Synonyms: recall, remember
>
> recollect
> verb [ I/T ]
> us
> /ˌrek·əˈlekt/
> to remember something:
> [ I ] *There were five young men in the car, as near as I can recollect.*
>
> - I also found myself recollecting the day that my daughter climbed her favorite tree and refused to come down.*
>   (From *TIME*)
>
> *As everyone recollects his version of events, the film flashes back to these developments.*
> (From *Hollywood Reporter*)
>
> He was so good at it, in fact, that he never needed to venture out to recollect specimens.
> (From *Wired*)
>
> *A simplicity of visual thinking to brood on and recollect, never to disentangle.*
> (From *The New York Review of Books*)
>
> *Many of our people still cry today when they recollect those emotionally wrenching days.*
> (From *Huffington Post*)
>
> *You walk in recollecting long romantic dinners, nights at the theater, and carefree vacations.*
> (From NPR)
>
> *He could not recollect all the falls, hallucinations and hospitalizations.*
> (From *Los Angeles Times*)

Although the dictionaries give "remember" as a synonym of "recollect", the verb "recollect" covers a narrower range, it does not include the meaning "to remember to do {something}"

As [this Google Ngram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recollect+to%2C+remember+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecollect%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremember%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crecollect%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremember%20to%3B%2Cc0) "recollect to" has had almost no use (in published books) since the 1920s. The uses that Google finds since then all seem to be reprints of 19-th century sources, or from even earlier.